# EF Code First forced eager loading

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm using EF 5 with Code First. I have a class that I want to always eager load some properties. I removed the **virtual** keyword but it's not eager loading:

```
public class Person
{
   public ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; } 
   public Profile Profile {get;set;}
}
```

So by turning off lazy loading, it won't auto eager load right? If so, how do I archive that without using Include()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, turning off lazy loading by removing the `virtual` keyword will not automatically enable eager loading. You have to `Include` the related `Entity` or `Collection` like so:

```
var personWithProfile = ctx.People.Include(x => x.Profile).First();
var personWithProfileAndEmails = ctx.People.
                                           .Include(x => x.Profile)
                                           .Include(x => x.Emails)
                                           .First();
```

This is a great read from the ADO.NET team blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link and it's very useful. I'm aware of the Include command. But there is no way to force the eager loading in the POCO class definition (or mapping file) right?

Comment: No, you want explicitly tell EF when to eager load the data. If you don't and EF just included all related entities there would be major performance issues. Essentially, every include statement translates into a SQL `inner join` and the query selects every column in the joined table as well.

Comment: An updated link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232 - this helpfully points out that Include with a lambda parameter is an extension method in the System.Data.Entity namespace so make sure you are using that namespace.