# Way of eager loading without using include

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity model:

```
class Test
{
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
    public virtual Town Town { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to eager load without using `.Include`.

The solution might look like this:

```
class Test
{
    [EagerLoad]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Address
{    
    [EagerLoad]
    public virtual Town Town { get; set; }
}
```

This solves the problem of having to include `Include` on every method that retrieves a Test... It will always need its address included.

Comment: I find that annoying as well.  I've looked.  Haven't found any other way myself.

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't want to. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804850/entityframework-eager-load-all-navigation-properties, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064905/ef-code-first-forced-eager-loading, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512285/entity-framework-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-eager-load-child-entities-wit for some reading material.